# How can I retrieve data from firebase database by its value in Web App?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a complaint portal and I want to assign id to the people who register.
My data structure in firebase like below:

```
fir-web-learn-51ffc
complaint
-Kwe6QXol8DV-uMDxIe7:"Hiii"
-KweCaYQrgG75BiJW3dA:"Hooooo"
```

and I have used this code for insertion:

```
 function submitClick()
 {
 var complaint=document.getElementById('complaint').value;   
 var database=firebase.database().ref().child("complaint");   
 database.push().set(complaint);
 }
```

for the above code, How can I retrieve the Name(Kwe6QXol8DV-uMDxIe7) by its value(Hiii). I have tried the code given on Google Firebase Documentation and Youtube but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use a Firebase query for that with `orderByValue`. So something like this:

```
var ref=firebase.database().ref().child("complaint");   
ref.orderByValue().equalTo("Hiii").once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key);
  });
});
```

Aside from the query itself, the main thing to note is the `snapshot.forEach()` in the callback. This loop is needed since a query can potentially match multiple results.